# aiohttp, asyncio and RuntimeError: Session is closed

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse and put JSON's async but getting:

> raise RuntimeError('Session is closed')
>
> RuntimeError: Session is closed

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from datetime import datetime
import time

start_time = datetime.now()

async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        DATA = response.read()
        return await response.read() 


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def put(url, session, data):
    async with session.put(url, data) as response:
        return await response.status()

async def bound_put(sem, url, session, data):
    async with sem:
        await put(url, session, data)

async def run(r):
    url_get = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?album_id=profile&rev=1&count=1&uid={}&access_token=qwerty&v=5.60"
    url_put = "http://127.0.0.1:5984/photosget/{}"
    tasks_get = []
    tasks_put = []

    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task_get = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, url_get.format(i), session))
            tasks_get.append(task_get)

            task_put = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_put(sem, url_put.format(i), session, DATA))
            tasks_put.append(task_put)

        responses_get = asyncio.gather(*tasks_get)
        responses_put = asyncio.gather(*tasks_put)
        await responses_get
        await responses_put

number = 1000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(number))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
print(datetime.now() - start_time)
```

I also tried to parse and put in one function but this doesn't work.

How I could use aiohttp and asyncio properly? Thanks for any advices.

Also in traceback more useful information:

```
 File "async.py", line 50, in run
    task_put = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_put(sem, url_put.format(i), session, DATA))
NameError: name 'DATA' is not defined
```

But if I define it global after imports like `DATA = ""` I got:

```
TypeError: put() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: oh yes, I'm sorry and also edited my question

Comment: always put full error messamge, not only last line. There are useful information like which line of code makes problem, from what module is this function, is there file with wrong name, etc.